# Can't browse HTTPS pages. TLS error. Outobox virus?

Tags: windows, ssl, tls

Suddenly I have lost an ability to browse HTTPS pages with all browser. Here is an example of simple Google search with Chrome

[image]

In other cases it can show blank page, or `TLS error` message.

**UPDATE**

I found, that if open SE page without login (HTTP), then it displays normally. Then, if try to login, it starts to open various advertisment pages and finaly shows SE page broken. Then, if open main SE page with HTTP without closing browser window, is starts to look following way

[image]

i.e. full of banners. Some of them are marked with "outobox". Apparently this is a huge virus, attacking system TLS/SSL certificates or something. How to get rid of it?

Comment: I assume you did an AV scan. What is your AV?

Comment: My AV is Kaspesky Internet Security. It sees nothing.

Comment: More precisely, it saw nothing this night, but this night I had no signs of outobox, just malfunctions.

Comment: Can you confirm it has done a full scan? Kaspersky comes with a live CD, it may be worth while doing a scan from that. Also are other browsers working OK?

Comment: Currently I am collecting data with their AVZ utility they said to me...

Comment: And Kaspersky said??

Comment: Nothing. Nobody said nothing.

Comment: Also see [SSL problems on chrome](https://superuser.com/questions/771588/ssl-problems-on-chrome).

Comment: 1st SS shows some kind of plugin is installed , akama.... is the advertising agency and 2nd ss shows DAMN SON so many ads , remove all plugins

Answer (score 1):

affected by either browser hijack malware or some nasty plugin that you have installed in chrome.
install malware bytes and scan your pc [malwarebytes](http://malwarebytes.org)

Mirror : [FileHippo](http://filehippo.com/download_malwarebytes_anti_malware/)

I also want you to recheck with  [hitman pro](http://www.surfright.nl/en/downloads)

Comment: Site you linked is HTTPS

Comment: @Dims new links added

Comment: malwarebytes found nothing, HitmanPro wants Internet. I have no internet ability now due to the problems on that computer.

Comment: @Dims - If you didn't update the signatures to Malwarebytes thats likely the reason you found nothing.

Comment: HitmanPro found only tracing cookies, nothing more.

Comment: Install Firefox, download from ftp.mozilla.org/pub/mozilla.org/firefox/releases/30.0/win32/en-US/ if needed. If you open this in your browser it's https again, so you might want to use your ftp program. Then use FF until your problem is solved!

Comment: @Ramhound how can I update signatures, if `outobox` is intercepting HTTPS communication?

Comment: @SPRBRN I have FF already installed. What next? After `outobox` "hatched", all HTTPS sites started to work, but with AD banners.

Comment: Some tips: set your system DNS to 8.8.8.8 (Google) or OpenDNS. Check your hosts file. And make a backup of important data!

Comment: @Dims - Since your installation is infected with extremely malicious software, any solution I could suggest, would require another computer with the infected hdd setup to be scanned by security software.

Comment: I have Kaspersky updated operating. It sees nothing. Other software also see nothing. Probably because they can't update, probably just because they can't. I have no problem to extract HDD and connect it to another computer and run any scan, but not sure it will be found.

Answer (score -2):

I would advise also run adwcleaner and spybot if you still have problems after malwarebytes and hitman pro, after using all 4 and still problems then it might be registry issue

Comment: SInce i can not comment directly to the user because of reputation, if you can not download or update things i suggest use another computer and download the software and updates o pen drive and then install them directly onto this computer. Look for tdss killer it might help as it could be rootkit to

Comment: yes, I used pen drive to move software to notebook. But some software require online update after installation. In this case pen drive can't help.

Comment: Give spybot a try you can download the defintion updates manual to install http://www.techspot.com/downloads/149-spybot-detection-update.html same with iobit malware fighter

Comment: Adwcleaner does not require you download updates it has them in the main program http://adwcleaner.en.uptodown.com/download