# SSL problems on chrome

Tags: google-chrome, ssl, ttls

I'm running Chrome 35 on windows 8.1. In the past month, every web site I go to gives either `SSL connection error`, or else `This webpage is not available`. I click on refresh three or four times before I get the page I want.  This is every page on every web site.  It is something I've never had before and I'm bloody tired of it.  Any suggestions?

Comment: So things are clear: you don't have the issue with HTTP? Only HTTPS?

Comment: Also see [Can't browse HTTPS pages. TLS error. Outobox virus?](https://superuser.com/questions/767800/cant-browse-https-pages-tls-error-outobox-virus).

Comment: Could be virus/malware, a misconfigured anti-virus or a proxy. Check proxy settings for HTTPS. Temporarily turn off antivirus software.

Answer (score 2):

Try clearing the SSL State in your advanced settings.

- Go to Settings.
- Click advanced settings at the bottom.
- Scroll down to Network and click "Change Proxy Settings"
- Go to the Content tab and then click "Clear SSL State"

Also try uninstalling and re-installing Chrome 35 if that doesn't work.

Report the bug to Google if it persists and switch to another browser.

Comment: The "Change Proxy Settings" in Chrome invokes Internet Explorer's settings, because Chrome reuses IE's proxy settings. Consequently with this process you clear IE's SSL state, not Chrome. Needless to say it didn't work for me when I tried it.

Answer (score 1):

The most frequent cause of this is the date and time on your computer is incorrect for your current timezone... check your system date/time to a known correct time source and make sure it is within 5 minutes of the known source.

Comment: Detail instructions on how to do this would help those users who don't know how to do it.

Comment: I can do that, but, whoever downvoted, was it worth downvoting when I have provided an answer that can, actually, be a cause as to why *all* SSL websites are not working correctly for the OP? A simple comment, such as from Ramhound, would have sufficed?

Comment: I did comment.  If I know how to do something, I almost never need an answer, so when I look for an answer to a problem I require detailed information.  *So I vote on answers as if I had that problem.*  I have high expectations but they can be reached.

Comment: I hear you, and I agree, some detailed instructions would have helped the OP, but a detailed answer for specifically Windows 8 would be limiting to Windows 8, when the problem of an incorrect system date/time for SSL sites/services is the same regardless of OS... so my answer could give other OS users an excellent clue as to "something to check" that may provide the answer to their problem... this is why I omitted detailed instructions.

Comment: You can do both if you mention the general fix first, and in the second paragraph particular steps for those on Windows 8, as in the question

Answer (score 0):

Delete your IE/Windows cache. `Control Panel\Internet Options\Browser History\Delete...`  then check all of the check boxes and `Delete`: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jWWoa9Ftxnk (not my vid)